# Docker build asp.netcore into image throwing dotnet restore error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to investigate using docker so I am very new to it.
I am running the docker build task from Visual Studio which is getting to

```
RUN dotnet restore "HoldingPage/HoldingPage.csproj"
```

In the output it is throwing the following:

```
error NU1101: Unable to find package <private package>. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

The package is in a private nuget store that isn't nuget.org. This package store is authenticated via windows authentication.
Packages are successfully retrieved from visual studio and when running the dotnet cli commands outside of docker.

Any ideas what I am missing to get it working?

Comment: I think you should change your dockerfile. You can provide source via '-s' flag at `dotnet restore` (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore).

Comment: I tried two methods with -s. The first was directly communicating with the share but this gave: The local source <share path> doesn't exist.
The second was mounting the network drive in windows but got the following: The local source 'Z:\' doesn't exist.